# Show only one variant price on shopify product page

Tags: shopify

All the variants for each product have the same price. When I use following code, it's showing price for all the variants. How do i show price of only one (let's say first) variant?

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    <div class="tablecell pricecur">
       {{ variant.price | money }}
    </div>
    <div class="tablecell pricecom">
       {{ variant.compare_at_price | money }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it would definitely help to know what language / framework you are using (Django?). What is also not clear is what `first_available_variant` returns. If it only returns one value you wouldn't have to iterate over it.

Comment: fixed the "first_available_variant" part. Copied from unsuccessful experiment. As for the framework, it says shopify in the title and tag.

Answer (score 0):

You use the following code.

`{{ product.first_available_variant.price | money }}`

`first_available_variant` - returns the first variant that is available ( a.k.a it's quantity is larger than 0 )